# only one record inserted at a time when try to save from two different client

Tags: php, mysql, database-deadlocks

I have tried to save agency information from two different clients at the same time but the problem is only one row inserted in the database but not shown any error to other client. 

Let me explain in another way, I have a web app which is running on two different machines but same server, I tried to save two differents information at the same time from both machine but only one record saved. Should I have to use any Deadlock prevention algorithm? Thank for your response in advance.

Here is my simple insertion code

```
$sql = "insert into  agency(agcode,agcname,proprietor,address,contact,email,gst)values('".$agcode."','".$agcname."','".$proprietor."','".$address."','".$cont."','".$email."','".$gst."')";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: Can you please give more details with clarity?

Comment: Data not inserted for all client when they try to insert in same time.

Comment: @Ajoy Please edit your question to show how you check for MySQL errors. When no errors occurred then the row has been added. Also, use prepared statements when you have a query with user inputs.